# How do I get Method of a smart contract deployed via Instance in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to get the method of a contract deployed via instance. This is what I did and I am getting an error when I try calling the method from the RegistryLogic contract.

```
Registry registry = bioreg.SaveLandDetail(_OwnerAddr,_regAddr,_ReferenceCode,_Longitude) 
different number of components on the left hand side than on the right hand side
```

**RegistryLogic.sol**

```
import "./ExternalStorage.sol";
import "./Registry.sol";

contract RegistryLogic is ExternalStorage{

    mapping (bytes32 => Registry) private _Registry;
    mapping (bytes32 => Details) private _Detail;
    mapping(address => properties) property;
    struct properties{
        Registry[] assets;
        }

function bioDataReg(
        address _OwnerAddr,
        string memory _FamilyName,
        string memory _FamilyRep
    ) 
    returns(address, Registry)
    {
        Registry _bioRegistry = new Registry(
            _OwnerAddr,
            _FamilyName,
            _FamilyRep);
        property[_OwnerAddr].assets.push(_bioRegistry);
            return (_OwnerAddr, _bioRegistry);
    }


function Registration(
        address _OwnerAddr,
        address _regAddr,
        Registry _bioRegistry,
        bytes32 _ReferenceCode,
        bytes32 _Longitude,
        bytes32 _Latitude) public
        returns(bool) {
        Registry bioreg = property[_OwnerAddr].assets[0];
        Registry registry = bioreg.SaveLandDetail(_OwnerAddr,_regAddr,_ReferenceCode,_Longitude, _Latitude)
```

**ExternalStorage.sol**

```
contract ExternalStorage{

    //Variables
    address[] public Registry;
    mapping(address => profiles) profile;
    bioData public biodataDetails;
    landDetails public land;


    //profile of a client
    struct profiles{
        uint[] assetList;
        }


    //BioData Details
    struct bioData{
        address OwnerAddr;
        string FamilyName;
        string FamilyRep
    }

    //Land Details
    struct landDetails{
        address OwnerAddr;
        address regAddr;
        bytes32 ReferenceCode;
        bytes32 Longitude;
        bytes32 Latitude
    }

 }
```

**Registry.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./ExternalStorage.sol";

/**
 * @dev Land Registry Contract module.
 *
 * This module is used to create instance of registry contract.
 */

contract LandRegistry is ExternalStorage {

    constructor(
        address _OwnerAddr,
        string memory _FamilyName,
        string memory _FamilyRep
    )public {
        biodataDetails.OwnerAddr = _OwnerAddr;
        biodataDetails.FamilyName = _FamilyName;
        biodataDetails.FamilyRep = _FamilyRep
    }


    function SaveLandDetail(
        address _OwnerAddr,
        address _regAddr,
        bytes32 _ReferenceCode,
        bytes32 _Longitude,
        bytes32 _Latitude
    ) external
    {
        land.OwnerAddr = _OwnerAddr;
        land.regAddr = _regAddr;
        land.ReferenceCode = _ReferenceCode;
        land.Longitude = _Longitude;
        land.Latitude = _Latitude
    }

    function FamilyDetails()
        external view returns(
            address,
            string memory,
            string memory,
            string memory,
            string memory
        )
    {
        return (
            biodataDetails.OwnerAddr,
            biodataDetails.FamilyName,
            biodataDetails.FamilyRep,
            biodataDetails.FamilyRep_HouseAddress,
            biodataDetails.FamilyRep_Mobile_No
        );
    }

    function RegistryDetails()
        external view returns(
            address,
            address,
            bytes32,
            bytes32,
            bytes32
            ) {
        return (
            land.OwnerAddr,
            land.regAddr,
            land.ReferenceCode,
            land.Longitude,
            land.Latitude,
            );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do `Registry registry = bioreg.SaveLandDetail(...)`.

But function `SaveLandDetail` does not return anything (let alone a `Registry` instance).